# android.hardware.camera2 zoom implementation

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have been searching for example or tutorial on how to implement zooming in android.hardware.camera2 api, but I have not found any example unfortunately.

If you ever encountered good example on how to implement zoom feature in android.hardware.camera2 kindly share it here.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This question was raised several months ago, more details can be found here:
[implement zoom in Camera2 api.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638280/implement-zoom-in-camera2-api)

Regards

Comment: Was not clear how to implement the scalar crop region control into the code shared by OP. Moreover, CaptureRequest class is used to capture single image, what if we are recording video? How to implement zoom-in, zoom-out?